# DateTime.TryParse in a conditional is throwing an exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

On both examples I'm giving it a **String** like the following: `26-03-17`

Dim mvarValor As String
Dim dateVarValor As DateTime

This code snippet is throwing an exception on the `TryParse`:

```
If Not mvarValor = Nothing AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(mvarValor, dateVarValor) Then
    Return Format(dateVarValor, mvarFormat)
Else
    Return strNull
End If
```

The next code snippet is **not** throwing an exception, but a `False` like it should:

```
DateTime.TryParse(mvarValor, dateVarValor)
If dateVarValor = Nothing Then
    Return strNull
Else
    Return Format(dateVarValor, mvarFormat)
End If
```

Why is the first code snippet giving me an exception?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Snippet #1 starts with `If Not mvarValor = Constantes.dtmNull AndAlso ...`, and Snippet #2 has `If dateVarValor = Constantes.dtmNull Then` - is it possible you meant dateVarValor and not mvarValor in Snippet #1? Also, what's the exception that's raised?

Comment: @rskar `InvalidCastException`, conditionals are meant to be like this

Comment: Ok, then, an InvalidCastException suggests that the issue is one of casting or conversion, in which case I'm very curious about what the datatypes are for mvarValor and Constantes.dtmNull. I'm wondering if the issue isn't TryParse, but with `=`.

Comment: @rskar check the update, there you will find the type of variables im using, also: Constantes.dtmNull is an enumerator which value is Nothing, like it is now on the conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParse` throws three types of exceptions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.100).aspx

you must be getting one of those.   Here is the proper usage of DateTime.TryParse

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

string parsedDateTime = null;

if (DateTime.TryParse(parseMe, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateResult))
{
    parsedDateTime = dateResult;
}
```

this snippet will parse the datetime without throwing an exception.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a Y2K compliant date.  The parser can't tell the year from 2 digits.  If you pass 2003-12-25 it will validate that the date does in fact exist, but 03-12-25 is ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, but why is the first case throwing an `Exception` and the second case is giving me `False`?